# ant tasks not working

Tags: ant, websphere

I run the following code to run my code in websphere 7,

```
<taskdef name="wasejbjar" classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.WsEjbDeploy" classpath="D:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar">
        <classpath> 
            <pathelement path="D:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar" />             
        </classpath> 
    </taskdef>
  <wasejbjar inputJar="${build.root.dir}/ejbtemp/${undeployed.ejb.name}-TMP.jar" wasHome="D:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/"  workingDirectory="${build.root.dir}/ejbtemp" outputJar="${build.lib.dir}/${undeployed.ejb.name}.jar" noValidate="false" noWarnings="false" noInform="true" trace="false" quiet="false"/>
```

When i try to run my websphere 7, I am always getting the error, Unable to parse setupCmdLine: null\bin\setupCmdLine.bat (The system cannot find the path specified).

Can anybody help please?.

Answer (score 0):

That means Ant doesn't know where WebSphere is installed on your server.  [This IBM post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013825401) suggests you need to set user.install.root to your WebSphere install directory.

Comment: I tried adding user.install.root as a variable in mycomputer properties as environment variable and also tried adding the value in path. But still it's not working. Can you help me please?